# Alpine.js x-for does not update browser if element nested in a reusable component

Tags: alpine.js

When I use `x-for` over an array, nested elements update correctly when the array changes. However, if those nested elements are inside a reusable component defined using `Alpine.data`, they do *not* update.

In my real-world example these are complex nested components implementing expandable accordions and new data is fetched from a server. However, I've boiled it down to the bare essentials here so that the component definition is completely empty. A button click changes the content of the array from [x,y] to [a,b].

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script defer src="https://unpkg.com/alpinejs@3.x.x/dist/cdn.js"></script>
</head>

<body x-data="{
    my_array: [{x:'x'},{x:'y'}],
    click() {
        this.my_array = [{x:'a'},{x:'b'}];
    }
}">

    <!-- Loop with plain div -->
    <template x-for="item in my_array">
        <div x-text="item.x"></div>
    </template>

    <!-- Loop with div nested inside component -->
    <template x-for="item in my_array">
        <div x-data="some_component" >
            <div x-text="item.x"></div>
        </div>
    </template>

    <button @click="click">Click me</button>

    <script>
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('some_component', () => ({}));
        });

    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

JSFiddle is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ps200306/zf3s8o45/3/).
Initially the output looks like this, with two iterations over the array:

[image: output before click]

On clicking and replacing the array, the first iteration updates but the second does not:

[image: output after click]

Answer (score 0):

If I parametrise the Alpine.data component with my data, everything works as expected:

```HTML
...
    <template x-for="item in my_array">
        <div x-data="some_component(item)" >
            <div x-text="item.x"></div>
        </div>
    </template>
...
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('alpine:init', () => {
            Alpine.data('some_component', (i) => ({
                item: i,
            }));
        });

    </script>
```

Updated JSFiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ps200306/zf3s8o45/6/).

<s>This gives me a workaround I can live with</s>. Actually it turns out to be a lot more complicated (and error prone) than that.

I've raised this as an [`Alpine.js` issue](https://github.com/alpinejs/alpine/discussions/3447).